# How to refresh a listview in android using asynctask?

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask

There are two Activities. The first Activity is having the list view to see what is being shared and the second activity has an edit text box (to input inorder to share) and a button. On clicking the button, it returns me the string which is the json response and I need to add this in the previous activity.

Now the problem is, when I refresh the first page fully hitting the server it gets the response but this is not what I want. It should not go back to the server. It should simply add in the list view adapter.

I have commented the code in the PostExecute(). I have tried the everyway but it is not reflecting. I am also posting my code for your reference.

```
    public class ShareAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<EventsStreamBean>> {

    public ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(EventStreamActivity.this);

    String success_share_val;

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<EventsStreamBean> doInBackground(
            String... result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        JSONObject jsonobj = new JSONObject(result[0].toString());

        success_share_val = jsonobj.getString(Constants.SUCCESS);


        //checks the success value
        if(success_share_val.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {            

         JSONArray events_stream_share_array = jsonobj.getJSONArray("streamArray");

         if(events_stream_share_array.length() > 0) {


                 for(int i=0; i<events_stream_share_array.length(); i++) {

                     EventsStreamBean events_stream_bean = new EventsStreamBean();

                     JSONObject events_stream_object = events_stream_share_array.getJSONObject(i);

                     events_stream_bean.setStreamId(events_stream_object.getString(Constants.STREAM_ID));
                     events_stream_bean.setStreamType(events_stream_object.getString(Constants.STREAM_TYPE));

                     events_stream_bean.setUserId(events_stream_object.getString(Constants.USER_ID));
                     events_stream_bean.setUserName(events_stream_object.getString(Constants.USER_NAME));
                     events_stream_bean.setUserType(events_stream_object.getString(Constants.USER_TYPE));
                     events_stream_bean.setUserAvatar(events_stream_object.getString(Constants.USER_AVATAR));

                     arraylist_events_stream.add(events_stream_bean);

                 }
         }else {
             Log.i("Test", "No Events Streams Available");
         }

        }

        }catch(Exception e) {}



        return arraylist_events_stream;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();

        this.pd.setMessage("Loading....");
        pd.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false); 
        pd.setCancelable(false);
        this.pd.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final ArrayList<EventsStreamBean> result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if(this.pd.isShowing()) {
            this.pd.dismiss();
        }


        Toast.makeText(EventStreamActivity.this, "Post shared successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        new EventsStreamAsyncTask().execute(temp_val);



        /*runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                //EventStream_Customadapter adapter = (EventStream_Customadapter) list_view.getAdapter();
                //adapter.clearData();

                adapter.updateData(result);
                //adapter = new EventStream_Customadapter(EventStreamActivity.this, arraylist_events_stream);
                //list_view.setAdapter(adapter);
                //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });*/

    }

}
```

Thank you

Comment: Wrong, you do not add it to the list's adapter - you add it to the lists's adapter's backing array, call list's adapter's `notifyDataSetChanged()` and call the list's `postInvalidate()`. You will probably want to setup a `Handler` object listening for these kind of messages from the other Activity as these two methods prefer being called from the UI thread (`postInvalidate()` runs off any thread really)

Comment: in onpostexecute call this adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: Hello I have tried this also but still the list does not get refreshed

Comment: you must call invalidate mtd on the listview object and call notifydatachanged mtd on listadpter in postexecute mtd of asynctask

Comment: if you are using separate Asyntack class then u can send adapter Object in constructor and write a method in adapter class which has notifydatasetchange() and in the post execute call adapter method like adapter.refreshList();